# Detect Repeated Characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

Is there a less brute-force way to accomplish something like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(b.id),
    COUNT(
       IF(
          phone = '1111111111' 
          OR phone = '22222222222' 
          ....
          OR phone = '9999999999', 1, NULL))
FROM table 
WHERE created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

**UPDATE**
Ideally, what I'd actually be able to detect any of the following:

- 4444
- 4444444444
- 1111111111
- 9999999999
- 99999

So any instance where the same digit is repeated in the field at least 4 times.

Comment: You are checking matching of exact string. How do you define **repeated characters** in your case?

Comment: I'd actually like to check for any instance where the same number is repeated at least 4 times.

Comment: same number or same digit? please make it a bit clearer. Didn't get it. If possible show your sample output.

Comment: I understand enough of your question to say: _No, you cannot do this in a less brute-force way_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

de ja vu?  Or maybe someone else asked this question last year.

```
SUM(RLIKE '0{4}|1{4}|2{4}|3{4}|4{4}|5{4}|6{4}|7{4}|8{4}|9{4}')
```

will count how many rows have some digit repeated 4 or more times.  (Note the use of `SUM` instead of `COUNT`.  This works because `RLIKE` will return 1 for true or 0 for false.)

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT '88888822222' RLIKE '0{4}|1{4}|2{4}|3{4}|4{4}|5{4}|6{4}|7{4}|8{4}|9{4}';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| '88888822222' RLIKE '0{4}|1{4}|2{4}|3{4}|4{4}|5{4}|6{4}|7{4}|8{4}|9{4}' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                       1 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```